# Insert Header row into multiple CSV files using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that splits a huge CSV file into multiple chunks of e.g. 50,000 rows, but only the first split file includes the header. I need to either amend the code to include the header in each separate file, or at the end of the script I want to add a piece of logic which will loop through all the files in the folder and add the header record (except for file 1).

Here is the current script:

```
Sub SplitCSVFile()
'Splits a text or csv file into smaller files with a user defined number (max) of lines or rows. The new files get the original file name + a number (1, 2, 3 etc.).

Dim sFile As String  'Name of the original file
Dim sText As String  'The file text
Dim lStep As Long    'Max number of lines in the new files
Dim vX, vY           'Variant arrays. vX = input, vY = output
Dim iFile As Integer 'File number from Windows
Dim lCount As Long   'Counter
Dim lIncr As Long    'Number for file name
Dim lMax As Long     'Upper limit for loop
Dim lNb As Long      'Counter
Dim lSoFar As Long   'How far did we get?

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

'Select a file
sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

'If the user cancelled
If sFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

'Ask the user for max number of lines per file.
lStep = Application.InputBox("Max number of lines/rows?", Type:=1)

'Arrays have zero as LBound, so we subtract 1
lStep = lStep - 1

'Read the file text to sText
sText = _
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sFile).ReadAll

'Put the text into the array vX. Carriage return–linefeed combination will add a new row to the array.
 vX = Split(sText, vbCrLf)

'Free memory
sText = ""

'Start a loop that will run until all rows in the array have been read and saved into new files. The variable lSoFar keeps track of how far we are in vX.
Do While lSoFar < UBound(vX)
   'If the number of rows minus lSoFar is bigger than max number of rows, the array vY is dimensioned to max number of rows.
   If UBound(vX) - lSoFar >= lStep Then
      ReDim vY(lStep)
      'lMax is set = last rownumber to be copied to vY.
      lMax = lStep + lSoFar
   Else
      'Else we dimension vY to the number of rows left.
      ReDim vY(UBound(vX) - lSoFar)
      'Last row to copy is last row in vX
      lMax = UBound(vX)
   End If

   lNb = 0
   'Now we copy the rows from vX to vY
   For lCount = lSoFar To lMax
      vY(lNb) = vX(lCount)
      lNb = lNb + 1
   Next

   'lSoFar keeps track of how far we got in vX
   lSoFar = lCount

   'Get a free file number
   iFile = FreeFile

   'Increment the number for the new file name
   lIncr = lIncr + 1

   'Save vY as a CSV file
   'Open sFile & "-" & lIncr & ".csv" For Output As #iFile
    Open Replace(sFile, ".csv", "") & "_" & lIncr & ".csv" For Output As #iFile
      'The Join function makes a text string from the array elements.
      Print #iFile, Join$(vY, vbCrLf)
   Close #iFile
Loop

Erase vX
Erase vY

Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Procedure SplitTextFile"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the line

```
Print #iFile, Join$(vY, vbCrLf)
```

with

```
Print #iFile, IIf(lIncr = 0, "", vX(0) & vbCrLf) & Join$(vY, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I just added an if statement to NOT do this for the first file, since it already had the header.

Comment: @user2725402 you do not need any additional check, the condition is already in the expression `IIf(lIncr = 0, "", vX(0) & vbCrLf)`.

Answer (score -1):

Using the lIncr = 0 value in the Print statement will produce a secondary header for the first csv that you split.

As the lIncr value is already = 1 when the Print statement is called, and that the header is the first line to print for the initial csv, the IIF check fails and includes a secondary header vX(0).

The IIF check is used to populate the header for each additional csv required.

The correct Print statement is...

Print #iFile, IIf(lIncr = 1, "", vX(0) & vbCrLf) & Join$(vY, vbCrLf)

Comment: If lIncr = 0, the first split will print 2 headers.

Comment: This is an _exact_ duplicate of the code from [the _accepted_ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906096/3025856), which was posted nearly three years ago. Please review existing answers before you contribute your own. If you have a different approach or even a better explanation it’s fine to submit another answer, even if one’s already been accepted. But in this case you’re offering the _same_ guidance with _less_ explanation.

Comment: @Jeremy...Read the comment and look at the code. There is a slight variation to the code which produces the correct result.

Comment: Aha, my mistake. Thank you for calling that out. Though, while we’re here, this is an excellent example of why it’s so important to explain your code. Please _edit_ your post and add the explanation from your comment so it’s really clear to future readers. Don’t leave the explanation as a comment.